# How are Sigmoid/Tanh functions forgetting and including information in LSTMs

Tags: neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I've read [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40761185/what-is-the-intuition-of-using-tanh-in-lstm) on here that discusses the intuition behind Tanh functions but it doesn't quite help me understand how the sigmoid and activation functions are forgetting and including information.

I guess I would like to understand what is happening to the data as it passes through [these functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysQGN.png) in an LSTM.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to look at a schematic drawing of an LSTM cell:
[image]

So I guess you have already read in the other question: sigmoid/tanh functions have a fixed output range. For sigmoid, this is `(0,1)`, while for tanh, it's `(-1,1)`. Both have an upper and lower value.

As you see in the above picture, there are 3 gates - but contrary to what you might believe, these gates aren't actually connected in a feedforward manner to any other neuron in the cell.

*The gates are connected to connections instead of neurons*. Weird huh! Let me explain. `x_t` is projecting a connection to `c_t`. They are connected with a connection, that has a certain multiplier (aka weight). So the input from `x_t` to `c_t` becomes `x_t * weight`.

But that's not all. The gate adds *another* multiplier to that calculation. So instead of `x_t * weight`, it becomes `x_t * weight * gate`. Which for the input gate, is equivalent to `x_t * weight * i_t`.

Basically, the *activation value of `i_t` gets multiplied with the value from `x_t`*. So if `i_t` has a **high value**, then the value coming from `x_t` has a higher value to `c_t`.  If `i_t` has a **low value**, then it could potentionally disable the input from `x_t` (if `i_t=0`).

Comment: That is really interesting, this drawing definitely is a really neat way to represent an LSTM. So, my understanding that the LSTM forgets information prior to adding new information to the Cell State is incorrect?

Comment: Additionally, am I right to assume that the initial activation value is arbitrary and the value value coming from `x_t` will vary throughout training? I guess what i'm trying to understand is how are these gates deciding what is important (high value) or not important (low value)?