# Why are there two different type of activation function used in LSTM cell?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

[image]

In a LSTM cell, there are 5 equations for 3 gate and 2 cell states.

Forget gate, Input gate, Output gate (I'm not sure it is correct name called) use ***sigmoid*** for activating between [0, 1].

In contrast, Ct' and Ht use ***tanh*** for activating betweenn [-1, 1].

I could not find why there are different activation function used.

Comment: Sigmoid output is not [-1,1] it is [0,1]

Comment: @BhanuTez, Sorry for confuse, I edited it

Comment: Check out this thread, maybe it'll be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40761185/what-is-the-intuition-of-using-tanh-in-lstm

Comment: @amityadav, Thanks for your kind, it is helpful for me.But I'm still confused why there is tanh function..

Comment: @RoyLee From the link above, the best reason seems to be "to overcome the vanishing gradient problem, we need a function whose second derivative can sustain for a long range before going to zero". This makes a lot of sense, considering that the simple RNNs suffer from vanishing gradients a lot. GRU and LSTM cells solve this problem by overcoming vanishing gradients and both use the tanh since its, as mentioned in the comment, higher order gradients can sustain for a long range before going towards zero. But perhaps someone else has a clearer understanding of this.