# Use of tanh activation function in input gate of LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, activation-function

While studying about LSTM , I got to know about use of 2 different activation functions in input gate - sigmoid and tanh. I got the use of sigmoid but not tanh. In this stackoverflow article [about use of tanh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40761185/what-is-the-intuition-of-using-tanh-in-lstm) says that we want the second derivative of it to be sustain for long time before going to zero , I don't get why he is talking about second derivative. Also, he kind of saying that tanh eliminates vanishing gradient(in 2nd para) but in all articles that i read they say that Leaky ReLU helps in eliminating it. Therefore I want to understand about tanh in LSTM.This is not duplicate question ,I just want to understand the previously answered question. Thank You!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: It's not such a big issue , atleast don't close this question if you can't help it‍♂️. My account is also going to terminate , So please.